# ArrayList of ArrayLists, how to use inner lists?

Tags: java, list, dynamic, arraylist

I have an ArrayList object to which I want to dynamically add ArrayLists.

However, since the compiler doesn't know what objects are going to be inside the outer ArrayList before the loop to add them runs, I can't use the inner ArrayLists as I normally would.

My code looks somewhat like this:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

 for(int i=8;i>0;i--)
 {
     list.add(i, new ArrayList());
 }

 for(int i=8;i>0;i--)
 {         
    tileRows.get(i).add( //add other stuff );
 }
```

How can I tell the compiler that the items in `list` are going to be of `ArrayList` type?

Bear in mind that I'm completely new to Java. If this is a stupid question I apologise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a `List<Whatever>`, and `Whatever` can be another interface/class that supports generics, like `List<String>`, so putting all this together you can declare a `List<List<String>>` and the compiler will be happy. Based on your code above:

```
List<List<String>> tileRows= new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for(int i=8;i>0;i--) {
    list.add(i, new ArrayList<String>());
}

for(int i=8;i>0;i--) {
    //here the compiler knows tileRows.get(i) is a List<String>
    tileRows.get(i).add("foo");
    //uncomment the below line and you will get a compiler error
    //tileRows.get(i).add(new Object());
}
```

Remember to always [program to an interface, not to a direct class implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was after. I suspected it would be something simple like this.

Answer (score 2):

You do it the same way you do with any other type of Object. You cast it:

```
((ArrayList)tileRows.get(i)).add( //add other stuff );
```

Or better yet, you use generics so you don't have to do that cast:

```
//this tells the compiler that your ArrayList will contain ArrayLists
ArrayList<ArrayList<Whatever>> list = new ArrayList()<>;
//now the compiler knows the get() function returns an ArrayList, so you don't have to cast it
tileRows.get(i).add( //add other stuff );
```

Answer (score 2):

This is Java Generic, and the correct use is some like this:

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

 for(int i=8;i>0;i--)
 {
     list.add(i, new ArrayList());
 }

 for(int i=8;i>0;i--)
 {         
    tileRows.get(i).add( //add other stuff );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<ArrayList<Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

in Java 7